# php page controlled interactive terminal

Tags: php, linux, terminal

I'm looking for a functionality where in, a custom php site I built, no frameworks or anything, shows a terminal kind of thing on a particular dedicated page, say ../terminal.php .

What it should do is have a terminal kind of thing displayed on the page. And when I type into that terminal like area, just like i would in a regular terminal, it displays the output as it would in a terminal.

For example say I typed in `sudo apt-get update` , it should show all outputs of the command and also be interactive, like when the terminal asks for permission to continue, the **Press y/n** thing etc.

Hope you get the image. I know a complete terminal is too much to ask for but any kind of terminal command running would do. It should be a live thing, as the terminal updates, the output display area should also update, be able to take inputs like "yes/no" or for matters like vim/nano etc. return errors etc. just like a normal terminal.

I tried `system()` and `shell_exec()`, they don't show outputs for apt-get update kind of commands.